# How can I redirect to the same webpage with get variables using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a page called "/spazio-web.php" on my root, and I need to redirect it to "/spazio-web.php?language=italian" using the mod_rewrite.

I used this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^spazio-web.php$ /spazio-web.php?language=italian [NC,L,QSA]
```

But this doesn't work beacuase I get an "Internal Server Error" when I call www.mysyte.it/spazio-web.php.

If I rewrite the rule like

```
RewriteRule ^spazioweb$ /spazio-web.php?language=italian [NC,L,QSA]
```

The rule starts to work and all works great.

Have you got a solution in order to solve this problem?
Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RewriteCond to avoid infinite redirect

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !language=italian
RewriteRule ^spazio-web.php$ /spazio-web.php?language=italian [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Did I have an "Internal Server Error" for the infinite redirect?

Comment: I dont see other reasons for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule to avoid redirect loop:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)language=italian(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^spazio-web\.php$ $0?language=italian [NC,L,QSA]
```